# How can I modernize this obsolete code and "query for window layout sizes directly"?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, obsolete

Prior to calling a FilePicker API, I call this:

```
async internal static Task<Boolean> EnsureUnsnapped()
{
    // FilePicker APIs will not work if the app is snapped
    var unsnapped = ApplicationView.Value != ApplicationViewState.Snapped;
    if (!unsnapped) unsnapped = ApplicationView.TryUnsnap();
    if (!unsnapped)
    {
        MessageDialog dlgLocFound = new MessageDialog("The picker cannot be displayed since the app cannot be unsnapped");
        await dlgLocFound.ShowAsync();
    }
    return unsnapped;
}
```

...which I got from "*Windows Store Apps Succinctly*" by John Garland, page 99.

But I get a warning on the first line (for "ApplicationView.Value"), namely: "*'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value' is obsolete: 'Value may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, query for window layout sizes directly.'*"

Okay, but how (do I "query for window layout sizes directly")?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586187/windows-8-1-how-to-fix-this-obsolete-code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileSavePicker and deprecated ApplicationViewState](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516313/filesavepicker-and-deprecated-applicationviewstate)